# Error building APK react native skia libreactskia.so No such file or directory

Tags: react-native, build, apk

Hello everyone i'm not sure if this question is already answered, but i can't find a solution anywhere...

So I want to build my .apk from my bare react native project but when i do: `.\gradlew assembleRelease` i get the following error:

```
> Task :shopify_react-native-skia:buildCMakeRelWithDebInfo[arm64-v8a] FAILED
C/C++: ninja: Entering directory `C:\Users\jpizaf\Desktop\uoc\assignatures\semestre-actual\tfg\projecte-react-native\emage\node_modules\@shopify\react-native-skia\android\.cxx\RelWithDebInfo\2c3m102b\arm64-v8a'
C/C++: clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':shopify_react-native-skia:buildCMakeRelWithDebInfo[arm64-v8a]'.
> Build command failed.
  Error while executing process C:\Users\jpizaf\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.18.1\bin\ninja.exe with arguments {-C C:\Users\jpizaf\Desktop\uoc\assignatures\semestre-actual\tfg\projecte-react-native\emage\node_modules\@shopify\react-native-skia\android\.cxx\RelWithDebInfo\2c3m102b\arm64-v8a reactskia}
  ninja: Entering directory `C:\Users\jpizaf\Desktop\uoc\assignatures\semestre-actual\tfg\projecte-react-native\emage\node_modules\@shopify\react-native-skia\android\.cxx\RelWithDebInfo\2c3m102b\arm64-v8a'
  [1/6] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/reactskia.dir/cpp/rnskia-android/SkiaOpenGLRenderer.cpp.o
  [2/6] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/reactskia.dir/cpp/jni/JniPlatformContext.cpp.o
  [3/6] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/reactskia.dir/cpp/rnskia-android/RNSkOpenGLCanvasProvider.cpp.o
  [4/6] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/reactskia.dir/cpp/jni/JniSkiaManager.cpp.o
  [5/6] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/reactskia.dir/cpp/jni/JniLoad.cpp.o
  [6/6] Linking CXX shared library ..\..\..\..\build\intermediates\cxx\RelWithDebInfo\2c3m102b\obj\arm64-v8a\libreactskia.so
  FAILED: ../../../../build/intermediates/cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2c3m102b/obj/arm64-v8a/libreactskia.so
  cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\Users\jpizaf\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.4.7075529\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe --target=aarch64-none-linux-android21 --gcc-toolchain=C:/Users/jpizaf/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=C:/Users/jpizaf/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot -fPIC -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -fexceptions -frtti -std=c++1y -DONANDROID -DSK_GL -DSK_BUILD_FOR_ANDROID -DFOLLY_NO_CONFIG=1 -DFOLLY_HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME=1 -DFOLLY_HAVE_MEMRCHR=1 -DFOLLY_USE_LIBCPP=1 -DFOLLY_MOBILE=1 -DON_ANDROID -DONANDROID -O2 -g -DNDEBUG  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc_real.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments -shared -Wl,-soname,libreactskia.so -o ..\..\..\..\build\intermediates\cxx\RelWithDebInfo\2c3m102b\obj\arm64-v8a\libreactskia.so CMakeFiles/reactskia.dir/cpp/jni/JniLoad.cpp.o CMakeFiles/reactskia.dir/cpp/jni/JniSkiaManager.cpp.o CMakeFiles/reactskia.dir/cpp/jni/JniPlatformContext.cpp.o CMakeFiles/reactskia.dir/cpp/rnskia-android/RNSkOpenGLCanvasProvider.cpp.o CMakeFiles/reactskia.dir/cpp/rnskia-android/SkiaOpenGLRenderer.cpp.o CMakeFiles/reactskia.dir/cpp/jsi/JsiHostObject.cpp.o CMakeFiles/reactskia.dir/cpp/jsi/JsiValue.cpp.o CMakeFiles/reactskia.dir/cpp/rnskia/RNSkManager.cpp.o CMakeFiles/reactskia.dir/cpp/rnskia/RNSkJsView.cpp.o CMakeFiles/reactskia.dir/cpp/rnskia/RNSkDomView.cpp.o CMakeFiles/reactskia.dir/cpp/rnskia/RNSkDispatchQueue.cpp.o CMakeFiles/reactskia.dir/cpp/rnskia/dom/base/DrawingContext.cpp.o CMakeFiles/reactskia.dir/cpp/api/third_party/CSSColorParser.cpp.o -LC:/Users/jpizaf/Desktop/uoc/assignatures/semestre-actual/tfg/projecte-react-native/emage/node_modules/@shopify/react-native-skia/android/../libs/android/arm64-v8a   -LC:/Users/jpizaf/Desktop/uoc/assignatures/semestre-actual/tfg/projecte-react-native/emage/node_modules/@shopify/react-native-skia/android/build/fbjni-0.2.2.aar/jni/arm64-v8a   -LC:/Users/jpizaf/Desktop/uoc/assignatures/semestre-actual/tfg/projecte-react-native/emage/node_modules/@shopify/react-native-skia/android/build/react-native-0.70.6-release.aar/jni/arm64-v8a -llog  -lfbjni  -lreact_nativemodule_core  -ljsi  -lturbomodulejsijni  ../../../../../libs/android/arm64-v8a/libsvg.a  ../../../../../libs/android/arm64-v8a/libskshaper.a  ../../../../../libs/android/arm64-v8a/libskia.a  -ljnigraphics  -lGLESv2  -lEGL  -landroid  -latomic -lm && cd ."      
  C:/Users/jpizaf/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot open output file ..\..\..\..\build\intermediates\cxx\RelWithDebInfo\2c3m102b\obj\arm64-v8a\libreactskia.so: No such file or directory
  clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.



* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

Execution optimizations have been disabled for 11 invalid unit(s) of work during this build to ensure correctness.
Please consult deprecation warnings for more details.

BUILD FAILED in 25s
120 actionable tasks: 16 executed, 104 up-to-date
```

I'll show my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "emage",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@eva-design/eva": "^2.1.1",
    "@klarna/react-native-vector-drawable": "^0.1.2",
    "@miblanchard/react-native-slider": "^2.1.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.11",
    "@react-native-camera-roll/camera-roll": "^5.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.0",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.5",
    "@shopify/react-native-skia": "^0.1.167",
    "@ui-kitten/components": "^5.1.2",
    "@ui-kitten/eva-icons": "^5.1.2",
    "clamp": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.6",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.8.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^4.10.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.13.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.18.2",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.6.0",
    "react-native-vector-image": "^0.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.7",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.72.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0"
  }
}
```

I've tryed creating a new project with just react native skia and it built the apk without a problem, but I have no idea what's wrong...

If anyone needs more info let me know.

Thanks ahead! <3

Comment: Late solution!! After all research, the problem was that the project folder was too nested inside windows file system and it doesn't like it... So I just moved the project at Desktop folder and it just worked

Comment: Dude, I am having this issue too... besides my issue post on the RNskia github this is the only other similar bug / problem i found related online. Is that really all you did to fix it?

Comment: Hi @hugger, yeah i just did that back in the day. It was something related on Windows file system that was too nested from the root